# Changing the Visuals of GRUB in Manjaro

Tags: grub2, manjaro

I am looking to make grub look nice. I know GRUB-Customizer exists but I have been told its incompatible with Arch. It is not in the pacman repository. So how would I make it a bit nicer.Mostly by increasing font-size and reordering and renaming the boot options.

Going above and beyond would be putting OS icons in.

Answer (score 0):

Enable AUR:

```
sudo nano /etc/pacman.conf
```

Add the following lines :

```
[archlinuxfr]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch
```

Run:

```
sudo pacman -Sy yaourt
```

Install `grub-customizer`:

```
sudo yaourt -S grub-customizer
```